# locate the tapestry component pagelink in selenium

Tags: selenium, tapestry

I am beginner in selenium. 
How to locate the element pagelink in selenium?

```
<li> 
   <t:pagelink page="NewCustomer" >New Customer</t:pagelink>                                     
</li>
```

I used this :
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("NewCustomer")).click();

but it didnt work for me.
Any suggestions?
Thanks;

Comment: try this xpath `//*[local-name()='pagelink' and @page='NewCustomer']`

Comment: It didnt work as well>

Comment: driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Customer")).click();
This is working, but i need to locate the element by one of the tag's attributes.

Comment: It should work: `//*[local-name()='t:pagelink' and @page='NewCustomer']` or `//*[local-name()='t\:pagelink' and @page='NewCustomer']`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the HTML source in your browser. You'll see that the Tapestry pagelink component renders itself as an ordinary HTML hyperlink, perhaps <a href="/NewCustomer">. That's what Selenium must look for. Something like this:

```
//*[local-name()='a' and @href='/NewCustomer']
```

But a better strategy might be to add a CSS class name or id other attribute specifically to make it easier for Selenium to find the element:

```
<li> 
   <t:pagelink page="NewCustomer" class="myNewCustomerLink">New Customer</t:pagelink>                                     
</li>

//*[local-name()='a' and @class='myNewCustomerLink']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bob, but i tried both of them. None has worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Customer").click()`, this will work.